# how to update the selected rows in same query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have 1 table table1, and a select query

```
select col1 from table1 where id <= 10;
```

I want to update the same records

```
update table1 set col2 = 'some value' where id < 10;
```

I want to do both the operations in 1 query and get the selected result also so that i can use it.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to update the actual table or the returned result set?

Comment: if u want to update it then why r u selecting it ? Just update it without using select query.

Comment: Why do you care if you are selecting another column?

Comment: @Yosi and even if the same column was selected, the value is already known while building the query, then why select at all?

Comment: I want the select result for further coding part.

Comment: Victor - Yep you are right..

Comment: i want to update only the selected records

Comment: Then the word - UPDATE isn't relevant for you, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can not update and select row using one single query, since both are different operation.
So you need to write 2 different queries.

If you don't need to update table and want temporary output, then @Yosi had provided you with perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to update it, you an use `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT col2 = CASE WHEN id<=10 THEN 'some value' ELSE col1 END
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql query using ***OUTPUT*** to get the updated vlaue

```
UPDATE persons  
SET LastName = 'test'
OUTPUT Inserted.LastName
where id<10;
```

If you need the old value after updation:

```
UPDATE persons  
SET LastName = 'test'
OUTPUT DELETED.LastName
where id<10;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6174a/7)